# Do I need to learn OpenGL 1.0 or can I skip to OpenGL 3/4?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I have never done game programming before and I'm starting to learn game programming using OpenGL with Java LWJGL,

I am learning OpenGL 1.0 redbook from http://glprogramming.com/red

Can I directly start with OpenGL 3 or 4, without wasting my time learning 1.0?

Comment: What is the question exactly? IMHO it is better to learn something how it actually is, not how it was years ago. Go get an OpenGL book that is up to date.

Comment: can you refer me a book?

Comment: i just want to ask , can a nob directly start with opengl 3.x

Comment: To answer your questions: no, yes. For Books you'd better use a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip that deprecated OpenGL 1.0; the earlier you become familiar with vbo, fbo, matrix- and  vector operations, the better.

That old fixed functionality apparently protects the user from dealing with algebra, but cg **is** applied algebra (and some calculus). Period.

There is the "OpenGL Programming Guide (**Eighth** Edition): The Official Guide to Learning OpenGL, **Version 4.3** " the newest version of that "Red Book". 
Be aware of editions; only use the newest (currently 8th) edition for your studies.

Comment: Thanks solkar. i have downloaded 8th edition on redbook and starting to read.

Answer (score 2):

Just skip to 3/4, OpenGL 1.0 is deprecated and there is no point learning it as it isn't supposed to be used in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to skip directly to OpenGL 3/4: older OpenGL interfaces use a very different architecture to draw objects on the graphic context, and this can bring you to confusion.

In general knowledge of the latest technology is better, as you will make use of updated state-of-the-art APIs.

IMHO difficulties in learning any of the OpenGL interface is the same, as there are complex concepts in both.